# Merge two files using Paste, but after the N row

Tags: bash, paste

I have two xlsxfiles, they are different but with only 1 thing in common: the date. I must convert to csv and merge them together.

**file1**

```
01/01/2013;horse;penguin
02/01/2013;cat;dog
03/01/2013;frog;whale
04/01/2013;mouse;bird
[...]
until nowadays, may 2017
```

No animals were hurt in writing this sample.

**file2**

```
14/02/2013;banana;cherry
15/02/2013;apple;mango
16/02/2013;orange;strawberry
[...]
until nowadays, may 2017
```

**This is the result I wish to achieve:** 
But the dates are in epoch (here I leave them not epoch, so you can read them).

```
01/01/2013;horse;penguin
02/01/2013;cat;dog
03/01/2013;frog;whale
04/01/2013;mouse;bird
[...]
13/02/2013;fish;elephant
14/02/2013;bear;owl;banana;cherry
15/02/2013;monkey;bat;apple;mango
[...]
```

The following is the script I made.

```
1) the dates needs to be epoch
2) the sheet2 does not contain the date, the date is printed in the final file for both and I use the date from sheet1

#!/bin/bash

# VARS #
XLSX=$1
SHEET1="sheet1"
SHEET2="sheet2"

P_PATH=/tmp/extract
EXTRACTCSV=$P_PATH/extract.csv
TMP_CSV=$P_PATH/temp.csv
CSV_SPLIT=$P_PATH/processed.csv
CSV_FINAL=$P_PATH/${XLSX}.csv

# START #
[ -d $P_PATH ] || mkdir -p $P_PATH
rm -rfv $P_PATH/*

########################
# ssconvert on sheet 1 #
########################
ssconvert --export-type=Gnumeric_stf:stf_assistant -O 'sheet='$SHEET1' separator=; format=automatic eol=unix' ${XLSX} ${EXTRACTCSV}"."${SHEET1}
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Ssconvert on $SHEET1 failed. Exiting."
  exit
fi

########################
# ssconvert on sheet 2 #
########################
ssconvert --export-type=Gnumeric_stf:stf_assistant -O 'sheet='$SHEET2' separator=; format=automatic eol=unix' ${XLSX} ${EXTRACTCSV}"."${SHEET2}
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Ssconvert on $SHEET2 failed. Exiting."
  exit
fi

######################
# Processing SHEET 1 #
######################
cat ${EXTRACTCSV}"."${SHEET1} | awk -F';' '{print $1";"$2";"$6}' > ${TMP_CSV}"."${SHEET1}
# Modify to EPOCH #
while read line; do
  colDate=$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $1}')
  colB=$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $2}' )
  colF=$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $3}' )
  # Skip when date not set
  if [ -z ${colDate} ]; then
    continue
  fi
  epoch_date=$(date +%s -ud ${colDate})
  echo "${epoch_date};${colB};${colF}" >> ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET1}
done <${TMP_CSV}"."${SHEET1}

######################
# Processing SHEET 2 #
######################
cat ${EXTRACTCSV}"."${SHEET2} | awk -F';' '{print $12";"$14";"$17}' > ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET2}


##########################
# Merge the csv together #
##########################
paste -d ';' ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET1} ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET2} | column -t > ${CSV_FINAL}
```

**My Request:**
The final command, the one to merge the 2 files together:

```
paste -d ';' ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET1} ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET2} | column -t > ${CSV_FINAL}
```

works good, but the second file is printed on the row of the 01/01/2013.

I don't know how to modify the logic of this script, to begin pasting the 2nd file from the row of 14/02/2013.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want sort and merge file(s) by date.

File1:

```
sort -n -k3 -k2 -k1 -t '/' -o File1.sorted File1
```

File2:

```
sort -n -k3 -k2 -k1 -t '/' -o File2.sorted File2
```

Merge:

```
sort -n -m -k3 -k2 -k1 -t '/' -o result.sorted File1.sorted File2.sorted
```

OR as a single line using virtual file descriptors:

```
sort -n -m -k3 -k2 -k1 -t '/' <(sort -n -k3 -k2 -k1 -t '/' File1) <(sort -n -k3 -k2 -k1 -t '/')
```

`-n` will sort the fields numerically instead of lexical.

`-m` merges two sorted files

`-k` will sort by year, then day, then month (fields 3,2,1 respectively)

`-t` sets the delmiter

EXAMPLE:

```
sort -m -k3 -k2 -k1 -t '/' <(sort -k3 -k2 -k1 -t '/' t2) <(sort -k3 -k2 -k1 -t '/' t1)


12/01/2012;banana;pear
15/02/2013;apple;mango
14/02/2013;banana;cherry
02/01/2013;cat;dog
03/01/2013;frog;whale
01/01/2013;horse;penguin
04/01/2013;mouse;bird
16/02/2013;orange;strawberry
13/03/2015;mango;papaya
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I do not think you understand the question. Or may be I did not express myself good. I don't know. I don't want to sort, it is actually done already. I need to paste the second file from the correct row. I'll try to edit my question!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved:

```
if [ $epoch_date -le 1360713600 ]; then
 echo "${epoch_date};${colB};${colF}" >> ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET1}.part1
else
 echo "${epoch_date};${colB};${colF}" >> ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET1}
fi

[...]

##########################
# Merge the csv together #
##########################
cat ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET1}.part1 > ${CSV_FINAL}
paste -d ';' ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET1} ${CSV_SPLIT}.${SHEET2} | column -t >> ${CSV_FINAL}
```

I split the file1 in 2 parts when I read it, 1 part contain dates and values before the 14 Feb, the other part the rest.

And well.. easy.